# Is it a good idea to encapsulate a property when it's a DOM element

Tags: javascript, oop, encapsulation

Is it a good idea to encapsulate what can be done in one property, when it is a DOM Element Object? For example:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.element = document.querySelector('.element')
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    this.a = new A()
  }

  someMethod() {
    // Here I need to set a style of this.a.element
    // should I manipulate the style directly:
    this.a.element.style.marginBottom = '10px'
    // or should I use a method:
    this.a.setElementStyle('marginBottom', '10px')
  }
}
```

Normally I would use a method, but in this case, the element already has a well-described API (since it's a [DOM Element Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp))

Comment: yes, it is. you can create methods on class A to encapsulate style operations or whatever (like the one you are showing)

Comment: It would make sense to follow this pattern if you would be building multiple styles for class A like class B does.